# Как получить данные из JSON и сохранить их в базу данных?

Tags: php, json

Имеется json строка следующего вида:

```
{"status":{"timestamp":"2021-05-03T16:47:16.362Z","error_code":0,"error_message":null,"elapsed":370,"credit_count":0,"notice":null},"data":{"2016-10-26T02:39:28.000Z":{"BTC":[1],"USD":[660.28167725,87283944,10525640015.288086]},"2016-10-27T02:39:28.000Z":{"BTC":[1],"USD":[702.39459229,89816296,11200777509.550781]}}}
```

Как получить из нее данные из data?

Интересует сама дата, USD в 3 вариантах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал так, но не смог вытянуть нужное:

```
$json = file_get_contents($json_url);
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item->USD;
}
```

Результат:

```
stdClass Object
(
[status] => stdClass Object
    (
        [timestamp] => 2021-05-03T16:47:16.362Z
        [error_code] => 0
        [error_message] => 
        [elapsed] => 370
        [credit_count] => 0
        [notice] => 
    )

[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [2016-10-26T02:39:28.000Z] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BTC] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                    )

                [USD] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 660.28167725
                        [1] => 87283944
                        [2] => 10525640015.288
                    )

            )

        [2016-10-27T02:39:28.000Z] => stdClass Object
            (
                [BTC] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                    )

                [USD] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 685.96984863
                        [1] => 93600296
                        [2] => 10936274615.024
                    )

            )
```

Comment: `Пробовал так, но не смог вытянуть нужное:` - все, что вытянули - это ненужное?

Comment: Нужны конкретные данные имел ввиду. Не смог переменные с данными получить, чтобы дальше в базу сохранять.

Comment: и как вы пробовали их получить?

Comment: Через foreach но у меня вообще ничего не вышло. Ранее не встречался с подобным json.

Comment: добавьте ваш код, поправим

Comment: Добавил foreach в вопрос, результат нулевой. Не могу получить данные, прописать верный $item

Comment: Вот думаю - какая связь между наименованием темы и тем, что у неё унутре.. ну кроме JSON, конечно...

Comment: @Akina видимо, автор смотрит вперед. потом появится следующий вопрос :)

Comment: @splash58 Ааа... ну тады подождём. Или, может, сразу сказать автору, что для сохранения в БД ничего из этого JSON получать не нужно? не, пусть корячится...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще преобразовать в массив, добавив true как второй аргумент в json_decode, а дальше примерно так

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach($data['data'] as $datetime => $v) {
   foreach($v['USD'] as $val) {
      echo "$datetime $val<br>\n";
   }
}
```